# c++ extracting decimal solution error

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Simple c++ question, so as you can see it creates a table and inputs variable a and also variable t answer, the problem is I don't know how to fix the `if ()`.
As you can see it has an error(typo). I don't know how to identify if variable t has example: `1` or `1.5`, if number have 1.(something here and it's bigger than number.**1**) then call one condition else call other.

```
int a,b = 18;
double t;

for (a = 0; a <= b; a++)
{
    t = 8 + (double)(18 - a) / 2;
    if (t >= *.1)
        cout << setw(9) << a << setw(20) << fixed << setprecision(1) << t << endl;
    else
        cout << setw(9) << a << setw(20) << t << endl;
}
```

Tried :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a,b = 18;
    double t;

    for (a = 0; a <= b; a++)
    {
        t = 8 + (double)(18 - a) / 2;
        if (modf(t, NULL) >= 0.1)
        cout << setw(9) << a << setw(20) << fixed << setprecision(1) << t << endl;
         else
            cout << setw(9) << a << setw(20) << t << endl;
    }

}
```

Fixed in my own way, still thanks 'Angew' he was the first to post modf():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a,b = 18;
    double t,z;
    int k;

    for (a = 1; a <= b; a++)
    {
        t = 8 + (double)(18 - a) / 2;

        if (modf(t, &z) >= 0.5)
        cout << setw(9) << a << setw(20) << fixed << setprecision(1) << t << endl;
         else
            k = t;
            cout << setw(9) << a << setw(20) << k << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for [`std::modf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf)?

```
double wholePart;
if (std::modf(t, &wholePart) >= 0.1)
```

Comment: hmm, but codeblock is showing error, not declared nullptr? Maybe i am missing some library?

Comment: @karolis I've expanded the answer.

Comment: Now it is showing modf is not declared in this scope, sorry i think i am using really old c++. Sorry for the trouble maybe without updating my codeblock etc, there is another way?

Comment: @karolis Have you `#include`d `<cmath>`? If the compiler is really old, you could also try `modf` without the `std::` qualification (and include either `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`).

Comment: tried without std::, and with include part when i press compile the cmd dialog just crashes. Updated the code, what i had when tried;

Comment: @karolis Edited again. My bad, I was convinced null is a valid value for the int part. It's apparently not, you need to provide an actual variable's address there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a modulus instead of dividing? (% symbol)  This will return the remainder of your operation.

```
double x = 1.1;
x = x % 1.0;
//x is equal to .1
```

Finding the mod of your number and 1 will return the decimal remainder, so change your if statement to:

```
if (t % 1.0 >= 0.1)
```

Comment: Question: Why do i need to use t % 1.0 if i need to find if .number is bigger than 1 or not? Please explain or i don't understand how does this % work.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?  Your code is trying to find out if the value after the decimal is larger than .1, correct?

Comment: Emilio, you are correct.  In c++ you can't directly use the modulus operator on doubles (I had tested it out in C#), some analogue to this would be needed...

Answer (score 1):

This will find the decimal part of your number:

```
double num = 23.345;
int intpart = (int)num;
double decpart = num - intpart;
//decpart = .345
```

As BoBTfish mentioned, this could become a problem with large decimals. Another possible(safe) solution is:

```
double integral;
double fractional = modf(some_double, &integral);
```

with this, your if becomes..

```
if(t_decpart >= .1)
    //
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question but yeah from you i got an idea how can this be done, we need to answer - int then we will get '.number' and if .number >= 1 then do something.

Comment: but it's a long and stupid way of doing it i think maybe there is something like 'Angew' suggested still can't understand why dosen't it work. Will try to search for it in google.

Comment: This works, like a charm. Still will wait for everyone else answer if anything new will make your answer correct. :)